How to rename the data.frame according to dictionary character
How to rename the data.frame ori_df  variable names according m_char ? (if the variable name not in m_char, then ignore it)
library(tidyverse)
ori_df <- mtcars
m_char <- c('new_mpg'='mpg','my_cyl'='cyl','new_x'='x')

cause 'x' not in ori_df names, so below code failed
ori_df %>% rename(m_char)


Use rename(any_of(m_char))
